# Correct place to advertise OpenVPN routes to EC2 Instances?

Tags: iptables, amazon-web-services, vpn, routing, openvpn

## Setup

I have a OpenVPN server working well in AWS. Everyone on my team can use it to reach any of the servers in AWS.

## Need

Now I have a new need. Now servers in AWS need to be able to reach one (but all would be fine) of the machines that connected via VPN. From the VPN server itself, I can reach the machine (which is a router) and all the machines it can see on its network. However, none of the other servers in AWS can.

### Questions

#### Where is the correct place to advertise (to machines in the datacenter) that requests for 10.10.10.0/16 (remote VPN connected site) should be routed through my VPN server?

#### Which interface on the VPN server address do I use?

## Details

- AWS VPC CIDR: 172.31.0.0/16

  - openvpn.conf: `push "route 172.31.0.0 255.255.0.0"`
- OpenVPN Server IP: 172.31.17.151
- OpenVPN Server client CIDR: 172.141.0.0/17

  - openvpn.conf: `server 172.141.0.0 255.255.128.0`
- Client to be reached: 10.10.10.1

  - openvpn.conf: `route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0`
  - openvpn.conf: `push "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0"`
  - ccd/commonname: `ifconfig-push 10.10.10.1 10.10.10.2`
  - ccd/commonname: `iroute 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0`
- Client peer to be reached: 10.10.10.101

OpenVPN `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:52:B7:00:71:F9
          inet addr:172.31.17.151  Bcast:172.31.17.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:172.141.0.1  P-t-P:172.141.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
```

OpenVPN iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:1194
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     all  --  172.31.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.127.0.0/20       172.31.6.110        tcp dpt:22
4    REJECT     tcp  --  172.127.0.0/20       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
5    ACCEPT     all  --  172.127.0.0/20       0.0.0.0/0
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.141.0.0/17       172.31.6.110        tcp dpt:22
7    REJECT     tcp  --  172.141.0.0/17       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
8    ACCEPT     all  --  172.141.0.0/17       0.0.0.0/0
9    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
```

Answer (score 2):

### The correct place to advertise the VPN routing to other machines in AWS is in the subnet routing table.

To do so:

- VPC > Subnets > [subnet to give access] > Route Table > [route table name]
- Routes > Edit > Add another route

  - Destination: `10.10.10.0/24` (matches "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0")
  - Target: `eni-a1b2c3d4` (id of the network interface associated with 172.31.17.151)

### You must also change the "Source/Dest. Check" of the network interface.

To do so:

- EC2 > Network Interfaces > [interface associated with VPN internal IP]
- Actions > Change Source/Dest. Check

  - Source/dest. check: Disabled

### What did not work was adding the route to a single machine.

I expected that I could get the same effect, but on a single machine, by doing:

```
sudo ip addr add 172.31.17.151 dev eth0
sudo ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 via 172.31.17.151 dev eth0
```

That did not work for me. I would love to know why.

Comment: *"That did not work for me. I would love to know why."*  Because that's not how it works. :)  The VPC network looks like Ethernet, but it isn't.  The default gateway looks like a router, but it isn't.   ARP is-at replies seem to be responses from the remote node, but they aren't.  It's a virtual network, so it (the network) has to know, via its own route tables, how to deliver the traffic.  These are side effects of how they created a massive IP network infrastructure that scales up seamlessly without stranding underutilized capacity or requiring capacity rearrangement or reallocation.

Comment: I was spent half a day to figure out why the traffic won't route between my VPN server and the VPC and turn out to be src/dst check problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Maybe you should upvote the answer to make it easier to find. I forgot about posting this and was directed here by Google just 3 weeks ago. That's why I use SO/SE!